# SQL Result (difference ) from two separate tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sum

I have two tables -

**INCOME**

```
Id - ProjectId - inAmount 
1  - 2              200   
2  - 2              100
3  - 1              100
4  - 2              100
5  - 1              200
```

**Expense**

```
Id - ProjectId - exAmount
1  - 2           50        
2  - 1           100
3  - 2           120
4  - 1           70
```

Now I want these results

**Result**

```
ProjectId - Total Income - Total Expense - Difference 
1           result         result          result
2           result         result          result
```

Remember: All this work I have to done in SQL

I have done the total income, total expense but what is the better way for difference?

----- edited......

**I have tried this**

```
SELECT sum(ex_amount) as expense, 
       sum(in_amount) as income,  
       sum(in_amount) - sum(ex_amount) as Difference,  
       project_name
FROM expense, 
     project, 
     income
WHERE expense.projectId = Project.id 
  AND income.ProejctId = Project.id
group by mh_name";
```

**edited second time**

Okey, please understand the original logic. Table expense have lot of records relation with project and table income also have the same now i want result of total income per project, total expense per project and difference per project

write your answer Using  these fields

**INCOME**

```
in_id  - in_source -  in_amount 
    1  - 2              200   
    2  - 2              100
    3  - 1              100
    4  - 2              100
    5  - 1              200
```

**Expense**

```
ex_id - mh_id -     ex_amount
    1  - 2           50        
    2  - 1           100
    3  - 2           120
    4  - 1           70
```

**main_head** or project

```
mh_id -  mh_name
    1  -  abc
    2  -  ase
    3  -  czz
    4  -  xys
```

Note in_source = mh_id

At this time i am using the following queries

for total income per project

```
SELECT sum(in_amount) as amount, mh_name FROM income, main_head WHERE income.in_source = main_head.mh_id group by mh_name Order By amount desc
```

total expense per project

```
SELECT sum(ex_amount) as amount, mh_name FROM expense, main_head WHERE expense.mh_id = main_head.mh_id group by mh_name Order By amount desc
```

### **SOLVED BY ME....**

```
SELECT
mh_name,
 income - expense AS difference 
FROM 
(SELECT sum(in_amount) AS income, in_source FROM income GROPU BY in_source) AS t1, 
(SELECT sum(ex_amount) AS expense, mh_id FROM expense GROUP BY mh_id) AS t2, 
(SELECT * FROM main_head) AS t3 
WHERE 
t1.in_source = t2.mh_id 
AND
t1.in_source=t3.mh_id
```

Comment: And what RDBMS?  Certain methods of doing this are not available in all providers.

Comment: I am using Equi Joining technique mySQL

Comment: This answer is coming income 21102262000 ex 114719157 dif 20987542843

Comment: What is the project table and what is mh_name?

Comment: And please, never use the implicit join syntax - it's way to easy to forget a join criteria.

Comment: Project table includes Id, mh_name(main head name or project name)

Comment: I have edited my Post, please read after .. edited second time

Comment: Dude, the answers put here before your edits still solve your problem after your edits.  All you need to do is change the table and field names.  I do not believe that it is appropriate to ask people to do that for you.

Comment: i am asking for suggestion, not for to solve... thats why i share the data here to guide me whats worng in my logic

Comment: I think there are plenty of correct answers in this thread...  There were a lot of helpful suggestions as well.

Comment: If you have found the solution to your problem, please post it as an **answer** and **accept** it. The question body is **not** the correct place to write your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SQL should work for you:

I am assuming there is a 1 to 1 relationship between the income and expense table.  Otherwise you might want to use some left joins.

```
SELECT i.ProjectId, 
       sum(inAmount) AS "Total Income",
       sum(exAmount) AS "Total Expense",
       (sum(inAmount) - sum(exAmount)) AS "Difference"
FROM   Income i
JOIN   Expense e
ON     i.project_id = e.project_id
GROUP BY i.ProjectId
```

Updated Answer that reflects the 0 - many incomes and 0 - many expenses possible:

```
SELECT i.ProjectId, 
       i.income AS "Total Income",
       e.expense AS "Total Expense",
       (i.income - e.expense) AS "Difference"
FROM   (SELECT ProjectId, sum(inAmount) AS income FROM Income GROUP BY ProjectId) i
FULL OUTER JOIN   (SELECT ProjectId, sum(exAmount) AS expense FROM Income GROUP BY ProjectId) e
ON     i.project_id = e.project_id
```

Comment: This will give wrong results, it will form a mini-cartesian product.

Comment: I agree, that would be good.  Since it seems like there are 0 to many income and 0 to many expenses after looking at his updated question.

Comment: @ypercube you are absolutely correct.  Look at my edited post.  I believe the second query is correct now.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    i.ProjectId, 
    sum(i.inamount) as TotalIncome, 
    sum(e.examount) as TotalExpense, 
    sum(i.inamount) - sum(e.examount) as Difference
from income i
inner join expense e
on i.projectid = e.projectid
group by i.projectid
```

**EDIT: we have all been wrong.  Because the joins without subqueries will join all matches, it gives us duplicate results.  Here is the correct answer and the right results, otherwise you are going to be getting double values:**

```
select 
    i.projectid,
    i.inamount as Income,
    e.examount as Expense,
    i.inamount - e.examount as [Difference]
from
(
    select projectid, SUM(inamount) as inamount
    from income
    group by projectid
) as i
full outer join
(
    select projectid, SUM(examount) as examount
    from expense
    group by projectid
) as e
on i.projectid = e.projectid
```

I kept up my original answer so that they can be compared.  The second query is correct.

Comment: Project 2 has 3 income records and 2 expense records.  This join yields 6 records for project 2.

Comment: I was going to update my answer after realizing that there were multiple incomes and multiple expenses per project in the tables, but this captured it perfectly.  Looks good!

Answer (score 1):

The problem faced by your attempt and several answers is that you are joining **sets** of data together.

Project 2, for example, has 3 income records and 2 expense records.  You don't actually want to join these together, you'll get 6 records as a result...

```
Id - ProjectId - inAmount        Id - ProjectId - exAmount
1  - 2              200           1   2           50
2  - 2              100           1   2           50
4  - 2              100           1   2           50
1  - 2              200           3   2           120
2  - 2              100           3   2           120
4  - 2              100           3   2           120
```

As you can see, this will cause serious duplication.

There are a few standard approaches.  Such as Correlated Sub-Queries or Inline Views.

Correlated SubQuery...

```
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT SUM(inAmount) FROM income  WHERE projectId = project.Id) AS income,
  (SELECT SUM(exAmount) FROM expense WHERE projectId = project.Id) AS expense
FROM
  project
```

Inline Views

```
SELECT
  project.Id,
  income.inAmount,
  expense.exAmount
FROM
  project
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT projectID, SUM(inAmount) AS inAmount FROM income  GROUP BY projectID) AS income
    ON income.projectID = project.ID
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT projectID, SUM(exAmount) AS exAmount FROM expense GROUP BY projectID) AS expense
    ON expense.projectID = project.ID
```

**EDIT**

A correction to Hamidam's attempt at using UNION...

```
SELECT
  projectID,
  SUM(inAmount),
  SUM(exAmount)
FROM
(
  SELECT projectID,      inAmount, 0 AS exAmount FROM income  GROUP BY projectID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT projectID, 0 as inAmount,      exAmount FROM expense GROUP BY projectID
)
  AS data
GROUP BY
  projectID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ge.id AS ProjectID 
     , TotalIncome
     , TotalExpense
     , TotalIncome - TotalExpense AS Difference
FROM 
    ( SELECT p.id
           , COALESCE(SUM(i.in_amount), 0) AS TotalIncome
      FROM project p
        LEFT JOIN income i
          ON i.projectid = p.id
      GROUP BY p.id
    ) ge
  JOIN
    ( SELECT p.id
           , COALESCE(SUM(e.ex_amount), 0) AS TotalExpense
      FROM project p
        LEFT JOIN expense e
          ON e.projectid = p.id
      GROUP BY p.id
    ) gi
    ON ge.id = gi.id
```